# ARMSim Recursion

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

New to ARMsim, trying to figure out recursion in the Fibonacci number sequence. If I input n I want to find the value of the fibonacci sequence at this index through the recursive case:

```
int fib(int N) {
# if (N == 0) return 0;
# if (N == 1) return 1;
# return fib(N-1) + fib(N-2);
# }
```

My current code:

```
.text
.global _start

_start:
mov r1 , #8

fib:
SUB sp,sp,#8
STR lr,[sp,#0]
STR r1,[sp,#4]

CMP r1, #1
BGT Else

MOV r1, #1
ADD sp,sp,#8

MOV pc,lr

Else:
SUB r1,r1,#1
BL fib
MOV r2,r1
LDR r1,[sp,#4]
SUB r1,r1,#1
BL fib
MOV r3,r1
LDR r1,[sp,#4]
LDR lr,[sp,#0]
ADD sp,sp,#8
ADD r1,r1,r2
ADD r1,r1,r3
MOV pc,lr
```

I was wondering where I am going wrong.
Any advice appreciated!